# MIDAS Pytorch Depth Estimation cant load pretrained model

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I have started coding with Pytorch MIDAS Depth Estimation. The example code worked perfectly in a jupyter notebook, but when I do it in a python script, I get the error: `No module named 'midas.dpt_depth'; 'midas' is not a package`

I have done `pip install timm`

The tutorial:
https://pytorch.org/hub/intelisl_midas_v2/

my code:

```py
import cv2
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model_type = "MiDaS_small"  # MiDaS v2.1 - Small   (lowest accuracy, highest inference speed)

midas = torch.hub.load("intel-isl/MiDaS", model_type)
```